# Determine if double word CAS is supported

Tags: c++, atomic

With the C++11 `<atomic>` library, you can take advantage of double-word CAS via the normal `atomic<T>::compare_and_exchange_X` family of functions by simply using a 16-byte type for `T`.  The compiler will fall back on spin locks, apparently, if the architecture doesn't actually support double-word CAS.

A common use for double-word CAS is the implementation of *tagged pointers* - pointers which carry an extra counter value in order to avoid the [**ABA problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) that plagues many lockfree data-structures and algorithms.

However - a lot of professional implementations of lockfree algorithms (such as Boost.Lockfree) don't actually use double-word CAS - instead they rely on single-word CAS and opt to use non-portable pointer-stuffing shenanigans.  Since x86_64 architectures only use the first 48 bits of a pointer, you can use the hi 16-bits to stuff in a counter.

Of course, the pointer-stuffing technique only really works for x86_64 as far as I know - other 64-bit architectures don't necessarily guarantee that the hi 16-bits will be available.  Additionally, the 16-bit counter only gives you a max value of 65536, so theoretically, in some absurdly pathological case, the ABA problem could still happen if one thread is pre-empted and then another thread(s) somehow performs more than 65,536 operations before the original thread wakes up again (I know, I know, a very unlikely scenario - but still insanely MORE likely than if the counter variable was 64-bit...)

Because of the above considerations, it seems that IF double word CAS is supported on some architecture, tagged pointer implementations should prefer to use a 16-byte pointer struct containing the actual pointer and a counter variable, rather than 8-byte stuffed pointers.

But... is there any way to actually determine at compile time if the **`CMPXCHG16B`** is supported?  I know most modern x86_64 platforms support it, but some older computers don't.  Therefore, it seems the ideal thing to do would be to check if double word CAS is supported, and if so use 16-byte pointers.  If not, fall back on 8-byte stuffed pointers.

So, is there any way to actually check (via some `#ifdef`ing) if `CMPXCHG16B` is supported?

Comment: c++ doesn't seem to define a 128bit primitive type, so any feature based on that type has to be platform/compiler specific, which means that even if some compiler provides `#define`s to know hardware abilities, code relying on this won't be portable.

Comment: Right, that's basically what I'm asking